# Promises chaining of asynchronous actions

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Considering the following code in ui5/javascript. Inside for loop the code should be executed always in the sequence: getData1, getData2, fnc1(i), getData3, getData4, fnc2(i) for each "i" before calling function fnc3(). As of now fnc3 is called before i is incremented:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= intNum; i++) {

    getData1(url1, true).then(function() {
        getData2(url2, true).then(function() {
            fnc1(i);
            getData3(url3, true).then(function() {
                getData4(url4, true).then(function() {
                    fnc2(i);
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
fnc3();
```

All four getData functions do some operations and then return a promise.

```
function getData() {
    var oModel = new JSONModel();
    return oModel.loadData(url, true); //asynchronous loading data and returns a promise
}
```

Any solution how can I make it work? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Put the `for()` loop inside a Promise and call `func3()` inside the then of that promise.

Comment: Use async/await? It would be much cleaner and more intuitive. https://blogs.sap.com/2019/01/17/writing-asynchronous-code-in-ui5-using-async-functions-part-of-es8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are turning promises in a callback hell, return each promise and chain it with `then` properly. use `let` instead of `var` also at for loop, `var` is not block scoped. you could add an if statement at last `then` block to run `fn3`:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= intNum; i++) {
  getData1(url1, true)
    .then(() => getData2(url2, true))
    .then(() => {
      fnc1(i)
      return getData3(url3, true)
    })
    .then(() => getData4(url4, true))
    .then(() => {
      fnc2(i)
      if(i === intNum) fnc3()
    })      
}
```